# Getting undefined value instead of a true or false

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery for my form validation, I wrote a function to check if the email already exists. When I alert inside the function I get a true or false value but when I call the function I get a undefined value. I need a true or false value once a email address is entered, can someone please help me?

I added my code to fiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cy5Pg/)

Html:

```
    <div style="display: none;" id="dialog-form" title="Create new master admin">
    <div class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</div>
    <form id="target" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">Please complete the form to create a new master admin (All form fields are required)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="20px"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="150px">Name</td>
                    <td colspan="2" valign="middle">
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="20" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Surname</td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="text" name="password" id="password" size="20" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td width="200px">
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="20" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="left"><span id="availability_status"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cellphone</td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="text" name="cellphone" id="cellphone" size="20" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="3">(A random username and password will be sent to the email provided)</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<button id="create-user">Create new user</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    var name = $("#name"),
        email = $("#email"),
        surname = $("#password"),
        cellphone = $("#cellphone"),
        allFields = $([]).add(name).add(email).add(surname).add(cellphone),
        tips = $(".validateTips");

    function updateTips(t) {
        tips.text(t)
            .addClass("ui-state-highlight");
        setTimeout(function () {
            tips.removeClass("ui-state-highlight", 1500);
        }, 500);
    }
    // Min max Length of field 
    function checkLength(o, n, min, max) {
        if (o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min) {
            o.addClass("ui-state-error");
            updateTips("Length of " + n + " must be between " + min + " and " + max + ".");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Check empty fields
    function checkEmpty(o, n) {
        if (o.val() == "") {
            o.addClass("ui-state-error");
            updateTips("please fill in " + n + ".");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Check email
    function checkEmail() {
        //if ( o.val() == "") {
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var bValid = true;
        $.ajax({ //Make the Ajax Request
            type: "POST",
            url: "master_admin_setup_submit.php", //file name
            data: "email=" + email, //data
            success: function (server_response) {
                //                                alert(server_response);
                if (server_response == '1') //if ajax_check_username.php return value "0"
                {
                    $("#availability_status").html('<img src="../images/not_available.png" align="absmiddle"> <font color="red">Email already used</font>');
                    //add this image to the span with id "availability_status"
                    bValid = false;
                    return (bValid);
                } else {
                    bValid = true;
                    //alert(server_response);
                    return (bValid);
                }
                //alert(checkEmail());



                //o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                //updateTips( "please fill in " + n + "." );
                //return false;
                //} else {
                //return true;
                //}
            }
        });
    }

    function checkRegexp(o, regexp, n) {
        if (!(regexp.test(o.val()))) {
            o.addClass("ui-state-error");
            updateTips(n);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 550,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            "Create master admin": function () {

                var bValid = true;
                allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
                bValid = bValid && checkLength(name, "username", 3, 16);
                bValid = bValid && checkLength(email, "email", 6, 80);

                bValid = bValid && checkEmail();
                alert(bValid);
                bValid = bValid && checkLength(surname, "surname", 5, 16);
                bValid = bValid && checkEmpty(cellphone, "cellphone");

                //  bValid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );
                // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com");
                //bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );
                if (bValid == true) {
                    $.post('master_admin_setup_submit.php', $('#target').serialize(), function (result) {
                        //                                    alert(result);
                        if (result === "1") {
                            $(function () {
                                $("#dialog-email").dialog({
                                    modal: true,
                                    buttons: {
                                        Ok: function () {
                                            $(this).dialog("close");
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            });

                        } else {
                            $(function () {

                                $("#dialog-message").dialog({
                                    modal: true,
                                    buttons: {
                                        Ok: function () {
                                            $(this).dialog("close");
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            });
                            // Reset form
                            $('#target')[0].reset();
                            // Close main dialog
                            $("#dialog-form").dialog("close");
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    $("#create-user")
        .button()
        .click(function () {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Comment: what is php code when form submited ?, Condition is not performed because the variable `bValid` is never been value .

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your `checkEmail()` function. It itself doesn't return anything, so if bValid is true before computatin of the formula `bValid = bValid && checkEmail();` this will be undefined.

If You call `$.ajax()` inside the function this is by default asynchronous, so with most probability You will have data returned by server after the script validating Your data will finish working. In other words Your function doesn't stop on `$.ajax()` and wait for result, but runs further, and the request is being processed parallely. You have to figure out how to make Your script wait for data returned by the server. If You are using only one ajax validator it can just call a function which finishes data validating and if success, posts data to the server. Otherwise You have to be aware, that  results may come to Your function in random order, witch also have to be managed.
I hope it helps.